# How to reload a request via cache in squid if URL is blocked?

Tags: tor, squid, privoxy

I have a simple and pretty basic squid3 configurations in my home server. I use it in combination with Tor and Privoxy. I have defined privoxy as cache_peer in squid configuration and an access list containing URLs this way:

```
acl censored    dstdomain       "/home/me/censored.acl"
never_direct    allow   censored
cache_peer localhost            parent    8118     0  no-query no-digest name=privoxy
cache_peer_access       privoxy allow   censored
```

Gradually I add new URLs to the "censored.acl" file to be loaded via proxy and it works.

What I need is to make the process dynamic. For every request that goes to a blocked URL I have two lines of squid log:

```
1337354630.541    716 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/403 521 GET http://bbc.co.uk/persian - DIRECT/212.58.241.131 -
1337354630.614     24 127.0.0.1 TCP_HIT/000 0 GET http://10.10.34.34/? - DIRECT/10.10.34.34 -
```

The second line is always the same. Is there anyway that I can reload a request in squid according the the response? Or if the request followed by or redirected to another URL?